# Create a symlink to a directory on another network machine

Tags: macos, shell

This is the problem: I am creating some files on a machine running some process, and I would like to have a second machine to create a symlink to this folder.

Not sure thou what should I do to make this happen. should I make a dir on my main machine and share it with the second? otherwise ls -s won't work if I specify a network path to the main machine (they are on the same network, but one just run terminal, no GUI or X server; the main machine is a mac with OSX lion on it).

The objective is to have machine 1 make these files, and machine 2 makes a symlink to this folder, use these files, then remove the symlink. I could copy the files over to the second machine, but these are pretty big files, and I have very little space available on the second machine (it is not a computer in the common form of the term...it is a SOC on a custom board, that I'm checking out, similar to the raspberry pi or the beagle bone).

Thanks

Comment: Basically youre going to have to mount a share from the main machine on second machine. However at that point the symlinks are probably moot since you can use a mountpoint anywhere in the second machines filesystem, unless its hardwired to only allow it in a certain spot. Cant really give you specifics without knowing more about the second machine. Id wager you may have issues though unless the filesystem on the OSX box is FAT or a normal linuf FS (ext*, resierfs, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the message; the second machine runs a very small distribution of Angstrom; so technically should be able to accept all the usual unix commands. The main box is a OSX Lion. The symlink is needed because the application that run on this test card needs these files to operate, and it would take hours for me to make them on this small processor, hence the idea to make them on my 8 core and then just use them while I have the board connected to the network.

Comment: No i get why youre doing it.. ive worked with embedded systems before. Thw question is does the card have a network sharing client available (nfs, smb, FUSE). Why not just run the build and then deploy the finished to the target system with `scp`, `rsync`, or by mounting the target machine on the Mac and then doing the copy to the target?

Comment: Glad that you have clear what I want to achieve; it is my first attempt at embedded systems, so I am still not clear on many things :)  AFAICT, the card can do scp, I use it to move files on it; while for the connection I just SSH on it and do what I can on it. I could build on the mac and deploy on the card, but I have no space....the available internal memory on the card is less than 60 mb (free space, and can't remove anything else from the OS, is already running at bare minimum), and these files used by the application that run on the card, takes almost 54 MB. Hence the symlink choice :(

Comment: Well in order to use the symlink you need to mount he fs on card. so first things first you need to see if thats possible... see if it can mount [nfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [smb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) shares.